# how to edit your Monitor Color Profiles (icm file)?

Tags: display, color-profiles

I made a color profile for my monitor by a monitor calibrator device that lost.
My profile looks great, but the image turn a little bit on blu and it looks cold.
How can I edit icm file in order to reduce cyano ?

BR
Giuseppe

Answer (score 3):

The [ICC](http://www.color.org/) provides an viewer/editor, which can be downloaded for free [here](http://www.color.org/profileinspector.xalter). They also provide a pretty comprehensive list of other tools for making, editing, assessing and converting color profiles: [commercial](http://www.color.org/profilingtools.xalter) and [open source](http://www.color.org/opensource.xalter) tools.

Comment: I tried several open source software with no luck, ICC Profile ispector looks fine, I'm looking how to reduce the blu value, but I need to set a 3D value for that.... to complex for me....